# R: Calculating values for all elements of an matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, apply

I have a vector of a sequence of values from 0 to n, called *seq*. I also have two column outputs each of length 1000 from a mathematical model previously run, *col1* and *col2*.

```
col1   col2   0   1   2   3   4 ... n
101    4      _   _   _   _   _ ... _
250    12     _   _   _   _   _ ... _
1007   8      _   _   _   _   _ ... _
```

My matrix *M* will have first column as *col1*, second column *col2*. I have created *M* so that I then have n+1 blank columns, one for each element of *seq*.

The rest of the elements of M will be populated using a very simple formula:

```
M[i,j+2] = (M[i,1]+seq[j])/M[i,2]
```

i.e. For element j of *seq* take the ith element of column 1 and add it to seq[j] then divide by the ith element of column 2.

It's straightforward, and it would be easy to do 2 for loops over i and j. But it would run for 1000 rows and for all n+1 elements of *seq*, so I fear this could slow me down immensely for lengthy *seq*. Is there a faster way to compute all of the elements of *M*, please?

Comment: You don't have to do two for loops. Just one will suffice as R does vector operations. `for(j in 1:n) M[,j+2] <- (M[,1]+seq[j])/M[,2]`. You can also use `apply` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

```
M[, 3 + 0:n] <- outer(M[,1], 0:n, "+") / M[, 2]
```

---

> This is a very simple and elegant solution. I'm going to test how fast the `outer` and `sapply` functions are, but it's fantastic to see how my problem can be solved with such a simple solution. Thank you.

`outer` is a vectorized solution, and is in principle the fastest. However, vectorization comes at a price of memory costs. Because though you work with one matrix, 3 additional copies are made during computation. If you have a really large matrix (the example in your question is far from being large, no worry), there will be a RAM hit and unlikely to be faster than a `for` loop, commented under your question, because no copy of the matrix is made during the loop.

Comment: This is a very simple and elegant solution. I'm going to test how fast the outer and sapply functions are, but it's fantastic to see how my problem can be solved with such a simple solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Example for `sapply` function.

```
M[, 3 + 0:n] <- sapply(0:n, function(x) return((M[,1]+seq[x+1])/M[,2]))
```